# Does JavaScript creates object literal with Object constructor under the hood?

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript creates object literal with Object constructor under the hood?

when we do `let obj = {};`
and `console.log(obj.__proto__)` it prints an object with constructor so does that mean object literal is being created by Object constructor under the hood

Comment: No. But both `{}` and the `new Object` constructor use the same internal mechanism under their hoods.

Comment: "*it prints an object with constructor*" - all that means is that objects created from literal inherit from `Object.prototype`. It doesn't mean any constructor was invoked. You can achieve the same yourself with `Object.create(Object.prototype)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi says, both forms use the same internal mechanism under the hood.

First, an object literal inside a JS script is *not* JSON, it is an "[object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)":

```js
// object initializer, NOT JSON
let myPet = {
    species: 'Dog',
    ageMs: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.24 * 5 // ~5 years, in millis
}
```

While no constructor is explicitly invoked by the literal notation, it's also not the case that the created object is *just* the literal properties; the JS engine still does some setup work. I've never dug into this before, but it appears that the spec calls that setup work "[OrdinaryObjectCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation)".